# htaccess - redirect to new domain and subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

even there are tons of articles about that problem i can not get this to work. 
My situation is like this: 
From one Domain e.g. english-domain.com i want a rewrite to the another domain into a specific directory e.g. german-domain.de/en. And each of these domains contains a hyphen. The typical generators are sadly not providing me with a working solution.For example the following code does not work 
RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?english-domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ german-domain.de/en/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It would be very thankful if you guys could point me to correct direction.
Thank you

Comment: That is because the target URL you rewrite to is _not_ a valid URL.

Answer (score 0):

What about this simply modified version?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?english-domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://german-domain.de/en/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I wonder though if that second `RewriteCond` you coded really is what you want. It will limit the rewriting to only the specific URL `https://english-domain.com/`, not to URLs having more than just the base `/` as path component... If you want to rewrite *all* URLs in that host, so for example also `https://english-domain.com/foo/bar`, then you need to remove that condition:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?english-domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://german-domain.de/en/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Oh, and obviously you have to make sure that the interpretation of `htaccess` style files is enabled at all and the rewrite module is installed.

---

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers host configuration instead of using `.htaccess` style files. Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).